# APK is not getting installed in kit kat; working with advanced versions

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-mobile

APk is not getting installed in kitkat, it's getting closed once we click on "install" button.
it is successfully getting installed via debugging and command prompt.
No screen related apps are installed on the phone.
please help me to find solution
Thanks in advance

Comment: "it's getting closed once we click on "install" button" -- apps are not opened when you click the "install" button. Apps are installed when you click the "install" button. Apps are opened when you click the "open" button after installation, or via a launcher icon. Assuming that you are doing one of those things, check LogCat to look for stack traces or other errors from your app's process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: see this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat"