# Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication ?Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, instant-run

I updated my Android Studio to version 2.0. But I had a problem, I don't know why?

The important error info:

> Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eallcn.rentagent.MyDebugEallApplication

I searched a long time, But I didn't find the right answer
you can see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app)

At the same time when I click **File->Project structure**
It shows this error:

[image]

Is there any problem somewhere in the libs? When gradle build the program the libs didn't load completely for current program. Is there any problem with Android Studio version 2.0?

When I use Android studio 1.4.0 to build and run the program. It works fine for me! But when I use the Android Studio 2.0, the problem shows up!

Why? Could you help me, please?

Here is detailed error log:

> 11-28 11:57:00.489 19890-19890/com.eallcn.rentagent.debug 
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.eallcn.rentagent.debug, PID: 19890                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.eallcn.rentagent.MyDebugEallApplication
>       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:537)                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4586)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.eallcn.rentagent.MyDebugEallApplication
>   at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:167)
>   at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:179)
>   at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:194)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:976)
>   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:532)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4586) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680) 
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.eallcn.rentagent.MyDebugEallApplication
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:155)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:179) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:194) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:976) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:532) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4586) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680) 
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/eallcn/rentagent/MyDebugEallApplication
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:155) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:179) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:194) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:976) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:532) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4586) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680) 
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.eallcn.rentagent.MyDebugEallApplication" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.eallcn.rentagent.debug-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.eallcn.rentagent.debug-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /data/datalib]]
>                                                                                                       at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:155) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:179) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:194) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:976) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:532) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4586) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680) 
>                                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I think this question is that:    it is just about android studio 2.0 and gradle version is not compatible!

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147) will solve your issue

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Disable the Instant Run option in Android Studio. Instructions are in the [Android Studio Instant Run documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run).

Instant Run tries to do hot swapping of your code; this causes the application class to be moved.

To disable Instant Run Go to File --> Settings--> Build,Execution,Deployment -->Instant Run ---> uncheck "Enable instant run"

Comment: This just happened to me on a Marshmallow device

Comment: The same issue on Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: It worked for me. but why is it that the instant run creates this issue? @peeyushpathak

Comment: First time it packs up the class in one dex file and second time it packs up in other dex file. So on 2nd time the interpretor searches for that particular class int first dex file but it is not present there.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that *disable this major feature of your IDE* is **NOT** a good solution? It’s like saying *use Studio 1.4*. Downvoted.

Comment: @mvai: It's not an ideal solution, but it may be the best solution available. If the problem is caused by Instant Run, then knowing that and being able to disable it at times is extremely valuable. Downvoting this answer is like shooting the messenger who told you not to take the shortest route home because there was an ambush waiting for you..

Comment: @LarsH then IMO the answer should clearly state that this is a temporary solution, that we are waiting for a fix, possibly linking to a bug report, explaining what you’ll miss if you disable instant run, mentioning there might be better solutions/workarounds.

Comment: @mvai: OK, those things could arguably be done to improve the answer (though 4 of the 5 seem obvious). But downvoting is not for "this answer could be even better" but is for "this answer is not useful". Whereas this answer is very useful. Feel free to add the details that you think would improve the answer; either here or on your own answer.

Comment: Instead of disabling instant run, better solution is to select Run option instead under Run Menu in Android Studio.

Comment: I cannot see the File -> Settings I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2

Comment: which os are you using

Comment: @peeyushpathak I'm using OS X El Capitan

Comment: I think "clean project" / "Re-build project" should be enough to fix the issue

Comment: This is a sad answer, but because Instant Run is so broken it's the only correct solution.

Comment: @clu cannot do much about it. So just wait till it is stable and working fine.

Comment: it could be a better if all of voters send a log to google, every time when this issue occurs...

Comment: Running Android Studio 2.3, Gradle 3.3, Android Plugin 2.3.0, this problem (and its solution in this answer) are still current. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: There seems to be an existing bug report for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224993 but it does not have much support. You might want to vote for it.

Comment: Now, Uninstalling the app and disabling the instant run made, .so files linkable to to code.

Comment: instant run is evil

Answer (score 22):

I had the same error after trying to use the 2.0.

I solved it by reverting some gradle changes:

**1/3:**

Changing:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
```

By:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

**2/3:**

Changing:

```
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
```

By:

```
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

**3/3:** (in `<project folder>/.idea/gradle.xml`)

And:

```
<option name="gradleHome" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/gradle/gradle-2.8" />
```

By:

```
<option name="gradleHome" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/gradle/gradle-2.4" />
```

I don't know what line is exactly the origin of the error, but with this three changes it was solved.

Hope that it helps you :)

Comment: The third step:   <option name="gradleHome" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/gradle/gradle-2.4" />  where can I  find , I want to change. I can find the code!

Comment: Hi, see the edited answer. (`<project folder>/.idea/gradle.xml`)

Comment: first 2 steps seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: What is `option name="gradleHome"`?  Where is that located.

Comment: If you have in your application build gradle : aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false), it is better to remove it. And one more thing DON'T use instant run until it is full stable, makes a lot of problmes

Answer (score 18):

I had the same error.

I solved it by cleaning the project ( Build > Clean Project )

Comment: underrated answer!

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer for me.  I was getting the issue without using Android studio so I just ran a gradle clean and gradle assembleDebug which does the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

Just go to Android Studio menu - Build --> Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get rid of this error by updating gradle-wrapper.properties to `gradle-2.14.1-all`, and cleaning/rebuilding the project.  Then it ran fine.  No other changes were needed (as those suggested in the above answer)...

Comment: Are you using ```com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1```? The error still exists for me after I upgrade it to ```com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6``` + ```https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip```

Comment: Yeah I upgraded to Android Studio Preview 5, it says I have to upgrade the gradle version for instant run. It seems they are making quite frequent alpha releases for bug fixes..

Comment: If you are working on Client's project / your own product, the 'alpha' or 'beta' builds are not suggestible to use; instead try to use one or 2 down versions ... Cause they are not stable one. 

And if you are testing the unstable build for bug fixing and improvements, even the android studio from cannery channel can help more in the process ...

Answer (score 4):

Changing to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

fixed issue

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error with Android 2.0 in stable channel.

What I did?
- I had an older version of the app already installed on the device (which was built using older version of the Studio) which I was trying to replace by running the newer app on device.
I just uninstalled the older version completely before running the new app and the trick worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just for those who want to update classPath with latest gradle plugin version, Where to find latest plugin version?

Check in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system and update your classPath. Latest one at current is

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'.
```

Always try to build with latest plugin version.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to disable Instant Run, just do a project clean and rerun.

Answer (score 2):

Change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'` fixes my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem and i solved it. In my case it was due to a mistake in global class ( Throughout Application context class ) , my mistake was in `AndroidManifest.xml` i have declared the Application class **`VolleyHelper`** as :-

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true" android:name=".VolleyHelper"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

but in `VolleyHelper.java` i don't have a Default constructor . So i added default constructor in `VolleyHelper.java` ( Application Class ) .

Answer (score 1):

you can also add this into your gradle to prevent making dex on debug

```
debug {
    // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
    // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
    // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
    minSdkVersion 21
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error will happen when you add a blank activity with .java file. So to solve this error 1st you have to Build the project again. Then run it. Solved
Thank You.

Comment: black Activity?

Answer (score 1):

In some Android devices with versions before OS 5.0 we get the error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication

We must disable "Instant Run".

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Built, Execution, Deployment` > `Instant Run`

Then disable the option `Enable Instant Run to hot swap code.`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to reboot my device.  Tried everything else first unfortunately so wasted hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **sharing your app** then another solution is

go to `Android Studio --> Build --> Build APK`

A pop up will come with `APK generated successfully`. `Show in Explorer` will get you to the generated apk folder.

Answer (score 1):

No need to disable "instant run".

1. **go to project's root using File Explorer**
2. **Finish Android Studio(AS)**
3. **delete(relocate somewhere) ".gradle" 's folder content**
   (to clean some cashs and old artifacts)
4. **in res folder clean off all inappropriate files**
5. **launch the AS again**
6. **in module's build.gradle set  `buildTypes { debug {minifyEnabled true` to false**
   (that looks like an error was in my proguard file)

Sync, compile and run the app again.

Answer (score -1):

I just update Android Studio to the last version (2.0 Beta 5). It changes itself to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'` and works like a charm.