# app is died, Occur ClassNotFoundException on android

Tags: android

when I run my app, app died and occur classNotFoundException.

perhaps, gradle problem ?

`compileSdkVersion =22`
`buildToolsVersion =21.1.2`
`minSdkVersion =19`
`targetSdkVersion =22`

I think code problem. 
settings, or gradle problem.

please advice for me.

logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid, PID: 27947
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid-1, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4301)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid-1, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4301) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate.. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat

Comment: there is not `BootstrapApplication` class in your app.