# cannot debug a Marshmallow device

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-studio-2.1

I'm trying to debug an application connected to an android 6 device.
if I compile the problem, copy in the device the apk and install manually the application runs, but if I try to debug it from android studio 2.1.2 I see this error message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sopla.Crash.CrashApplication
```

if I remove the custom boostrap application I obtain the same error with the main activity class.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the problem, as explained here [Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication ?Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat) is the instant run option.
I disabled it and now it works