# Android Studio 2.3 Update not opening app [Instant Run Service]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-run

I recently updated the Android Studio to 2.3. When I hit the instant run button, It compiles the app but doesn't open the app on the Android device. Even 'Hot Swap' is not enabled after that, it shows "No active 'app' launch". Any idea what I might be doing wrong. I tried creating a new project, but this error exists in that also.

I am getting below error:

```
 Error while executing: am startservice
 com.example/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService Starting
 service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
 cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
 cmp=com.example/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService }
 Error: Not found; no service started.
```

Comment: I met the same issue on an android 5.1 device. but on android 6.0.1 device, it's work, the default activity is launched.

Comment: same for me. Do you find any solution for it?

Comment: me too have the same issue my gradle is not getting complete it is about 3 hours of time

Comment: I also had issues with my update, although different issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573603/after-the-last-sdk-update-android-studio-cant-find-any-google-play-service-or/42574247#42574247

Comment: My problem solved after this : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant run in Android Studio 2.0 (how to turn off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off)

Answer (score 11):

Got the same error after updating. As already noted, there's an open discussion on this topic. So far, the only work-around is that you actually **disable** `instant run`, that's the only thing that worked for me. You can do so in `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run`:[image]

Turn it off and run the app again and it's going to work. That's the best we can do at this point.

Comment: Yeah that worked fine for me too, thanks. Are there any other issues with this configuration?

Comment: @Matz I have no idea, to be honest. What I also discovered is that my bulit-in emulator stopped working after an update that I did recently. I haven't figured out a fix for that yet, I had to use a physical device. And then I moved to IntelliJ Ultimate, and there it works. Weird how they break stuff with updates.

Comment: Thx, I'm know on the Android Studio 3.0 Preview and there it's working very fine ... I moved for Kotlin and that's a nice approach too that the emulator is working :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a device related bug. There is a google issue discussion:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235879

They have found some solutions:

- Asus devices: you have to allow auto-start for apps you want to start with instant run https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1013752
- Devices with MIUI: you have to disable MIUI optimization (see other answer in stackoverflow) https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579815/1341576

Comment: It used to work perfectly before updating AS. Do you still think its device issue?

Comment: Google said they will repair AS with version 2.4 (see the code.google discussion). In the meanwhile they are testing single devices that are affected. From a google project manager: "Thank you for your patience while we investigated this issue. The problem seems to be that some manufacturers have customized their devices and added some sort of "Auto-start" blocker.".

Comment: To answer your question, you are right they broken AS istant run with the new update (I have your issue too) but the bug affects only some devices where there is some sort of "auto-start" blocker (like my Asus zenfone)