# Instant run doesn't work anymore for my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

I have 4.4.4 (19) Android and I can't use instant run with new version (2.3) of Android Studio:

[image]

[image]

Why did they do it? It worked on the version before this one.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ***
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        renderscriptTargetApi 25
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ***
}
```

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571175/android-studio-2-3-instant-run-not-working?rq=1

Comment: @JasonC in his case this new button "instant run" is active, but app crashes on running, in my case the button isn't even active (I can't click it)

Comment: Add the Gradle file, please... The error is right there. Can't run on API 19

Comment: @cricket_007 added Gradle file

Comment: Doesn't have sufficient RAM and OS in your phone.Sometime it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(emphasis mine)

> In Android Studio 2.3 and higher, Instant Run significantly reduces the time it takes to update your app with code and resource changes. After deploying your app **to a target device running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher**, you can click Apply Changes  to push certain code and resource changes to your running app without building a new APK—and, in some cases, without even restarting the current activity

[Android | Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run)

**Note** You can still set the `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdk` version to the latest API levels without affecting the majority of your code. (minus any deprecated methods)

Comment: I don't understand what was slow in old "instant run" feature and why changed it so now it doesn't even support 4.* OS...

Comment: Because 5.0 introduced the ART runtime. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

Comment: why didn't they left old "Instant run" for 4.* and just use new one for older versions...

Comment: I'm not on the Android Development team. You're asking the wrong person.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying it.. mb someone of them will see it. but what about gradle file?

Comment: I just wanted to see what versions you had set. But doesn't really matter, just that you are running API < 21 on the device is why it is disabled

Answer (score 0):

If you still not find solution then just go one way.Probably it work for you.

Update your sdk with **Platform tools** whatever Device you want to run.

Instant need platform tools.

Like nougat need 24.

Thanks hope this will help you.