# Android instant run - Installation failed with message Failed to esatablish session

Tags: android, android-instant-run

I am trying to run the app by enabling instant run but getting this message and failed to install app.

> DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
>
> Error while Installing APKs

Here is the screenshot.[image]

any solution?

Comment: try to remove your app after then restart your mobile its work for me

Comment: Thanks for the replay, Yes I tried but same result. Even though after clean and rebuild the app.

Comment: Then i think something went wrong with your manifest file  like wrong package name for service or other

Comment: No there no any problem with manifest package it's working fine when disabled `Instant Run`

Comment: yes but there is no proper solution ..
If u have proper sol. then plz comment here

Comment: Humm.. I am trying to find the solution now.. I'll update once I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this issue by disabling MIUI Optimization in my RedMe Note3 mobile by going to

> Settings--> Additional Settings--> Developer Options--> Turn on MIUI optimization --> Disable --> Restart device

As suggested by Kishan Gohel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579815/2462531) Thanks man.. May it useful for some one like me..