# Android release build generated in Android Studio 3.0 unable to install

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Android build generated using "Android Studio 3.0 (with gradle-4.1)" is not installing in phone, where as able to install the build generated by Studio before to this version.

Able to install the build through USB, but when trying to install the same build generated in other device, not able to install. In device it shows "App not installed".

Comment: upload the error logs you get while installing the build

Comment: First do few of the things.
01. Clean and Rebuild the Project
02. Disable the Instant Run.

Comment: I tried the same but no luck.

Comment: Rebuild and Build>Build APK /Generate Signed APK instead of  Run>Run

Comment: There are lot of changes in 3.0 first you read this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html .Also you have to add the error log here., "App not installed" with only this we cannot know what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks slee.. It worked..Do know know what was the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before making the build, check if you have instant run enabled or not.
It is enabled by default and can be found under 
File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run

Disable it and then try rebuilding the apk.
Check comments and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571175/android-studio-2-3-instant-run-not-working/42735938)

Now, if you are building a release apk and you have selected Signature Version V2(Full APK Signature), in the generate signed apk dialog, app might not install after the build is made.

You need to re-generate a signed apk with both the signature versions enabled i.e V1 & V2. You will get this option under Build -> Generate Signed APK.

Combining this with the disable instant run thing, your apk should install smoothly.