# After the last sdk update, android studio can't find any google play service or firebase library

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I had a working project, but yesterday I updated the android sdk and sdk tools.

and suddenly I'm getting

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0
```

This is happening in all my android projects!

Even in an ionic project, that was also working fine, now it is giving me 
`Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.`

Anything changed in the update to android studio 2.3 or api 25r3 ?

If I go to module settings > dependencies and try to add these libraries from the `choose library dependency` window, I can't find them :

[image: when searching foor play-services]

My SDK tools :

[image]

I already have everything configured correctly, since the project was already working.

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'fr.tvbarthel.blurdialogfragment:lib:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.mattluedke:snowshoelib:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}





apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Anyone has the same issue ?

Comment: can you show sdk tools screenshot

Comment: updated the question, in fact I also have an ionic project, which was also working and is now giving me `Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.`

Comment: can i see your project level build.gradle file

Comment: added build.gradle

Comment: What i think is the Android_Home environment path is incorrect please check it as might cause this problem

Comment: thanks a lot, can you help me with something, how do I know what the android_home should be exactly ?

Comment: which operating syatem you are using?

Comment: OS X, my sdk path was `/Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137120/discussion-between-nitesh-mishra-and-dany-y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was solved by removing `google repository` from the SDK manager and installing it again.

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```