# App does not launch through Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I run my Android Studio project from the editor to my phone, nothing launches.
Everything compiles fine, however no activity is started when it completes. I then have to open the application manually with my phone, and the newest code is indeed updated.

Here is a snippet from my Android Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".view.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**What I have tried:**

- Using a different physical device
- Using a virtual device
- Going into "Edit configurations" and selecting a default activity for launch

Comment: "Nothing launches" may not be enough information to help you. Have you any error message, traceback, something?

Comment: Yes you are right, I hadn't seen the error message at first. I ended up having the same error as this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570016/android-studio-2-3-update-not-opening-app-instant-run-service I had to disable instant run. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having the same problem as this post:

[Android Studio 2.3 Update not opening app [Instant Run Service]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570016/android-studio-2-3-update-not-opening-app-instant-run-service)

Solution is to **disable instant run**.