# Instant run does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, adb

I'm getting this issue in android studio 2.3 when I click on run:

```
03/09 19:02:36: Launching app
$ adb shell am startservice 

com.a890m.s/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService
Error while executing: am startservice com.a890m.s/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService

Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.a890m.s/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService }

Error: Not found; no service started.
```

Comment: I solved with this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat>

Comment: Yes, disabling that shit is the best option for now

Comment: When I try to disable it it gives me another error saying that instant run is needed with grade 3.3

Comment: For now I have got a temporary solution I. E see that u r app is running on the phone and then click on the run button on android studio so with this it acts like hotswap and whatever changes u want get applied

Answer (score 5):

This issue is only in Android Studio 2.3 which is still open in google issue [Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137335)
You can resolve it (for time being not a permeant solution because Instant run is needed) by disabling instant run in your android studio.
goto-> Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

Comment: File->Settings-> Choose [Build, Execution, Deployment] item on left side.
Expand Debugger option. 
Select [Instant Run] then on right side, click (uncheck) the "Enable Instant Run to hotswap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)"
This worked to resolve this issue so I could debug on my Alcatel phone.  Why don't other answers explain how to turn off Instant Run?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error before and the solution that works for me is to Try  unplug and plug the cable again and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for some specific devices because some manufacturers have customized their devices and added some sort of "auto-start" blocker. For affected Asus devices, for example, you can fix this issue by enabling Auto-start for your app with Asus's Auto-start Manager. See this page for details: https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1013752

But different manufacturer seems to do this differently. For example, for LeEco devices, you can allow "auto-launch" under settings. See this issue (https://github.com/openstf/stf/issues/407#issuecomment-247852532) for info on how to enable auto-launch for your app.

You can Google how to turn off such autostart/autolaunch feature for your specific device to get Instant Run to work. You can also just use the emulator.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may still need to disable auto-start depending on what system image you are using on the emulator.

Comment: I am using the clean android images provided from Google in the SDK Manager. I cannot find any option for auto-starting.